# default service account for maintenance plan backups on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

What is the default service account used for backups created with the Maintenance Plan Wizard? I am trying to put the backup files on a share on a different server, and that service account will require access to the folder there.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations do not shed any light on the issue, and they do not inform the questioner what was wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a BACKUP query under a certain Windows/SQL Server account, it is actually the SQL Server Agent account which "does" the BACKUP and needs full control permissions to the UNC path (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/find-which-account-sql-server-service-is-running-backup-under)).